# How would you add all the numbers inside a single element of an array?

Tags: java

How would you go about adding the total number to all the integers inside an array element?
My code below is what I have and the issue is the multiple numbers are all displayed in different rows but I can't get them to add together because its all considered one integer.

This is what my output looks like.

```
462085
361250
351477
328955
```

But when I attempt to alter the numbers in any way I get something like this,
+2

```
462087
361252
351479
328957
```

When I really want to get just get the total sum of the numbers.
Desrired Output:

```
1503767
```

I attempted to use .parseInt() but that did not seem to make a difference.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;



public class babySort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("src/babynames.txt");



        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String input;
            String maleNames;
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // process the line
                String[] inputSplit = input.split("\\s+");
               // System.out.println(inputSplit[2]);
                int maleBb = Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[2]);
                System.out.println(maleBb);







            }

            

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }

}
```

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question a little? Provide a sample input, what you expect the output to be, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the digit sum of each element in the array?

Comment: I edited my post to show expected output, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the total. Declare a variable to compute the total with before your loop. Add the values to the total. Print it after your loop. Like,

```
int total = 0;
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] inputSplit = input.split("\\s+");
    // int maleBb = Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[2]); // what is a maleBb?
    total += Integer.parseInt(inputSplit[2]);
}
System.out.println(total);
```